# Why does DataAnnotation MaxLength(8192) not work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, data-annotations

I am working on a project with Entity Framework 6.1.3 in C#, and I want to set an maximum limit on some binary data.

`[MaxLength(8192)]` does not work is this a bug? There seems to be an upper limit to it.

`[MaxLength(4096)]` this works surprisingly?

Am I using DataAnnotations correctly?

```
//[MaxLength(4096)] <-- this works
[MaxLength(8192)]
public Byte[] MediaData {get; set;}
```

Result:

```
MediaData = c.Binary()
```

Expected:

```
MediaData = c.Binary(maxLength: )
```

Also tried.

```
[MaxLength(8192)]    // this does not work either
public string Text {get; set;}
```

I could fix it manually but It annoys me that DataAnnotations does not work automatically. What are your experiences/recommendations with DataAnnotations?

Comment: in SQL Server, the maximum length of `char`, `varchar`, `binary`, `varbinary` is ***8000***. So maybe that's why it does not work. You can try some smaller value instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from MSDN, look at the bold part :D

for string part:

> nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ]
>   Variable-length Unicode string data. 
>   **n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 4,000**. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size, in bytes, is two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for nvarchar are national char varying and national character varying.

and for the binary part:

> varbinary [ ( n | max) ]
>   **Variable-length binary data. n can be a value from 1 through 8,000.** max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes. The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes. The data that is entered can be 0 bytes in length. The ANSI SQL synonym for varbinary is binary varying.

so there is actually a limitation here.

Comment: The OP isn't talking about **nvarchar** - he's talking about **binary data** (e.g. `varbinary` in SQL Server, which has a limit of **8000 bytes**)

Comment: what the hell? why these tiny limits? how are you supposed to fit images and stuff?

Comment: @ColacX looks like you need to use `image` type (instead of `varbinary` which I believe the `byte[]` is mapped to that by default). That means you need to map/specify the column type explicitly (to `image` instead of `varbinary`).

Comment: @Hopeless this is not okay since MediaData can be video as well.

Comment: @ColacX well you may think `image` can store just images? it's also a kind of binary data type but its maximum length is about 2GB. it stores all kind of bytes like as `varbinary` can do. In fact `image` here means `copy` rather than what you think. It's a data type supported in SQL Server. You may want to search more about that.